# What is the meaning of (Any) in Raku - specifically the ()?

Tags: raku

Here is an experiment with Raku:

```
> my $x
(Any)
> my $y=1
1
> my @a=[1, 2]
[1 2]
> my %h=a=>'b'
{a => b}
> say "nil" unless $x
nil
```

I can see that `[]` indicates an array literal, `{}` a hash literal.

I can also see that `(Any)` behaves like nil - returning false in the boolean context shown above.

I find the `(Any)` interesting.  The documentation tells me that `Any` is just one of the god classes in Raku.  But what do the parenthesis `()` around `Any` tell me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the REPL, the result of the expression is shown using `say`.  The `say` function calls the `.gist` function on the expression.

`Any` is a type-object.  Type-objects have a `.gist` method that puts the parentheses around them.

The `put` function is almost the same as the `say` function, but it calls the `.Str` function on the expression.  And that produces a warning, because you cannot really stringify a type object.  Observe the difference:

```
$ raku -e 'say Any'
(Any)

# raku -e 'put Any'
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .raku, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block <unit> at -e line 1
```

See [Classes and Objects](https://docs.raku.org/language/classtut), [Type System](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem), [Type Objects](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#index-entry-Type_objects) for more information.

Comment: But it's true that, for the newcomer, it might look like an one-element list. Maybe something we could change in the future?

Comment: But that is a general "problem" in Raku:  a `(foo)` is **not** a one element list, it's just a grouping of something.  A `(foo,)` (note the comma) *is* a one element list.

Comment: To a newcomer just `(Nil)` or similar would have been more expected.  The `()` are important to differentiate it from the string `'Nil'` which is not quoted in REPL.

Comment: jjmerelo: if any change were done, I'd recommend `(Type:U)` or `Type:U`, although ultimately `(Type)` is just an idiom that needs to be learned. Sadly you can't override/wrap Mu's gist and have it automagically work for everything else — that could be kind of cool to have a module do type objects as `Type` but in green/grey/yellow whatever.

Comment: I like the idea of `(Foo:U)`  I'm pretty sure just putting parentheses around type objects dates from an era when there were no type smileys yet.

Comment: I've started a problem solving ticket for this: https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/issues/194

Answer (score 8):

There is a very simple answer.

`Any` is a class. Specifically it is the default base class for every other class.

In Raku you can pass around a class the same way you can pass an instance.

```raku
my $a = 1;
my $b = $a.WHAT;

say $b;
# (Int)
```

The thing is if you try and use the class as if it were an instance, bad things will happen.

```raku
say $b + 4;
# ERROR: … must be an object instance of type 'Int', not a type object of type 'Int'.
```

---

When you use the REPL it automatically calls `.gist` and prints the result.

`.gist` is meant for humans to be able to understand what the value is.

So then why would it add parenthesis around the name of the class?

It makes sense to me that it does that to tell you it isn't a `Str` or some other instance.

```raku
say 'Str'; # say calls .gist
# Str

say 'abc'.WHAT;
# (Str)

say 'abc'.WHAT.^name;
# Str

say 'abc'.^name;
# Str
```

All but one of those is an instance of the `Str` class.
(Guess which one.)

---

Basically the parens tell you that it would be an error to try and use it as an instance.

Comment: Thank you Brad.  This answer is helpful in that it brings out the difference between an object instance and a type object.  And the summary sentence is also useful.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to lizmat's excellent answer, it's probably relevant to explain what's going on here.

When you say `my $foo`, you're effectively saying `my Any $foo`.<sup>1</sup>  And when you say `my @foo`, you're implicitly saying something closer to `my Any @foo` which is the same as `my Array[Any] $foo` (but in a positional container).  That lets you put anything into the array, because it's typed, well, as `Any`.

When you access an object that's undefined, it returns an undefined value — but that value is still typed.  It just happens that by default, the type is `Any`.  We could, however, change some things and it would probably become clearer:

```
my Str $foo;
say $foo;    # a Str that's undefined, so '(Str)';
my $bar;     # implicitly typed Any
say $bar;    # an Any that's undefined, so '(Any)';

my Int @foo = 0, 1, 2;
say @foo[0];   # an Int defined as 0, so '0'
say @foo[1];   # an Int defined as 1, so '1'
say @foo[3];   # an Int that's undefined, so '(Int)'
```

As lizmat pointed out in her answer, `(Type)` is the default representation of the `.gist` method, which is used by `.say`, for undefined values.<sup>2</sup>

The reason that they don't return `Nil` is because by definition, `Nil` returns `Nil` for every method that's called upon it (with a few exceptions like `Bool` where it returns `False`) — it's sort of like Objective-C's `nil`.  But an undefined type object still has uses: for instance, you can still call methods on it, as long as they don't access attributes.  There are some times where that can be a very useful property, and it's what actually enables you to do something like:

```
  my Foo $foo .= new;
```

Which is syntactical sugar for

```
  my Foo $foo;
  $foo = $foo.new;
```

`$foo` is a an undefined type object, so we actually still call `Foo.new`.

---

1. As raiph rightly points out in the comments, I should have noted this isn't *exactly* what's going on, but from an end-user perspective, is close enough and much less complicated.
2. One can always override this, and I've done that for some of my classes that have names suspiciously close to or identical to builtins that add a clear prefix so I don't get them mixed up.

Comment: Thank you @user0721090601.   All of that is helpful.
The piece that is missing for me is that the _gist_ of  `(Any)` is that it behaves as an undefined value but `.gist` doesn't tell me that `my $x;` has no value.  

Something like `(Any[nil])` would be nice.

Comment: Ross Attrill: I can understand that.  That's just one of those customs that Raku developed.  Once you understand that (Type) means "undefined value of type Type") you just get kind of used to it.  Perhaps one could add `:U` to be `(Any:U)` which is explicitly an undefined value / type object.  I tried seeing if I could pull that off in a module, but wrapping the existing method isn't working for some reason =\

Comment: Actually, you can use `Mu.^find_method('gist').wrap( method { self.defined ?? (callsame) !! ( (callsame).substr(0,*-1) ~ ':U)') } );` but unfortunately, most built in classes explicitly define their gist (it probably saves a little bit in method resolution)

Comment: This is probably an effect of method caching at compile time.  And the fact that classes in Raku know of their parents, but parents do not know of their children.

Comment: .oO ( "When you say `my $foo`, you're implicitly saying `my Any $foo`." To which I say, "As the bell of awareness tolls its sweet tone, and [pedagogical facilitations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORjyXcLDd9M&t=1m31s) lie in weight in their zone, so at Wit's end the truth rings out; What's rung first is Socrates' doubt." Or, more prosaically, when one writes `my $foo`, you're implicitly writing `my Mu $foo is default(Any)`. This is quite reasonably left as a footnote. Which, in turn, suggests this belongs on the first rung of the ladder. Which, in turn, suggests it's a lie. "Wait. What?" )

Comment: raiph: yeah, I should have left it as "effectively saying" to better imply it's not *exactly* what's going on under the hood, since what's actually going on probably only complicates things further.  I'll update to adjust the wording slightly

Comment: I've reason to believe my prior comment wasn't clear enough and that this follow up might be in order: My propositions serve as elucidations in the following way: anyone who understands me eventually recognizes them as nonsensical, when he has used them—as steps—to climb beyond them. Then again that might also be out of order. Hmm. I'll let you decide.