# Determine if a variable in Raku is set

Tags: raku

I intentionally avoid the term `defined` because a variable may very well have a defined value but the `.defined` method will return false (Failures, for instance).

Is there any way to determine whether a variable has had a value set to it?

```
my $foo;
say $foo; # (Any), its type object, no value assigned
my Str $bar;
say $bar; # (Str), its type object, no value assigned
my $abc = Str;
say $abc; # (Str), the type object we assigned to $abc
```

How can we disinguish `$bar` (no value set, typed as `Str`) from `$abc` (value set to `Str`)?

Given that `$bar.WHICH == $abc.WHICH`, but `$bar.VAR.WHICH !== $abc.VAR.WHICH`, and methods like `.defined` will return false for each, is there any quick and easy way to determine that there is a set value?

I supposed it could be checked against the default value, but then there'd be no way to distinguish between the value being by virtue of unset, versus by being set in code.

Answer (score 6):

Variables are always set to some sort of value.

If you don't set it to a value, a value will be chosen for you.
Specifically it will be set to the default.
(If you don't choose a default, it will be set to the type object.)

```raku
my $abc;

say $abc.VAR.default.raku;
# Any
```

```raku
my Int $def = 42;

say $def.VAR.default.raku;
# Int
```

```raku
my $ghi is default(42) = 2;

say $ghi.VAR.default.raku;
# 42
```

---

What you're asking for isn't really something that Raku supports.

You could probably fake something close though.
(Every instance of `Mu.new` is unique.)

```raku
sub is-not-set ( Mu $_ is raw ) {
  $_.self =:= $_.VAR.default
}

my $abc is default(Mu.new);
my $def is default(Mu.new) = Any;
my $ghi is default(Mu.new) = Mu.new;

say is-not-set $abc; # True
say is-not-set $def; # False
say is-not-set $ghi; # False
```

The thing is that assigning `Nil` will also set it to the default.

```raku
$def = Nil;
say is-not-set $def; # True
```

As will looking up the default and assigning it.

```raku
$ghi = $ghi.VAR.default;
say is-not-set $ghi; # True
```

---

I don't think you should worry about such things.

If you really really need something to happen the first time you assign to the variable, you could do something like this:

```raku
my $abc := Proxy.new(
  # this FETCH only needs to return the default
  # as this Proxy gets replaced upon the first assignment
  FETCH => -> $ { Any },

  STORE => -> $, $value {
    # replace the Proxy with a new Scalar
    $abc := do { my $abc = $value };

    say 'first assignment just happened'
  },
);

say $abc;
# Any

$abc = 1;
# first assignment just happened

say $abc;
# 1

$abc = 2;

say $abc;
# 2
```

The `do` block is just there so that `$abc.VAR.name` returns `$abc`.
Otherwise you could just write `$abc := my $ = $value`.

Comment: Alright, the "are always set to some value" is probably where some of the confusion that the OP in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818213/what-is-the-meaning-of-any-in-raku-specifically-the had, and makes jnthn's reasoning on why `(Type:U)` isn't as great of a fill in for the gist method.  I wonder if there's a way to work that out in the documentation to make this clear

Answer (score 5):

I think both the values are identical, but the containers have different [type constraints](https://docs.raku.org/language/containers#Type_constraints).

Try

```
my Str $foo;
my  $bar = Str;

use Test;

cmp-ok $bar, &[===], $foo, 'The values are identical';
isa-ok $bar, Str;
isa-ok $foo, Str;
isa-ok $bar.VAR.of, Mu;
nok $bar.VAR.of.isa(Str), 'The container $bar is not of Str' ;
isa-ok $foo.VAR.of, Str;

done-testing();
```

```
ok 1 - The values are identical
ok 2 - The object is-a 'Str'
ok 3 - The object is-a 'Str'
ok 4 - The object is-a 'Mu'
ok 5 - The container $bar is not of Str
ok 6 - The object is-a 'Str'
1..6
```

Answer (score 4):

Is that a general question or an implementation problem? If the latter, maybe (ab)using roles is an option?

```
role isUnset {}; 
my Str $a = Str but isUnset; 
say $a ~~ isUnset; 

# meanwile
$a = 'set'; 
# ...
$a = Str;

# and then
say $a ~~ isUnset; # Now False
```

Comment: I don't consider this abuse at all. One of `role`'s intended important (and thus far seldom used) roles is as a mixin, with the significant limitation that a mixin may not survive mutation of the object receiving the mixin, and in turn one of the important (and thus far seldom used) roles of mixins is to attach metadata. If the role is mixed in to a type object, then the mixin is guaranteed to be lost if the object is mutated. This seems to me to be a perfect use of `role`s that provides a perfect simple solution to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

`my Str $bar` and `my $bar = Str` result in the same thing, both are of type Str but have no definite values. `Str` is a type object, not a value.

`.defined` would return `True` if you'd give `$bar` a definite value, such as `"Str"` (note the quotes surrounding the bareword).

Comment: "result in the same thing": not really, though.  `my Str $bar; $bar = 3` errors because `$bar` is typed as `Str`, but `my $bar = Str; $bar = 3` does not because `$bar` is not typed

Answer (score 1):

You might try to assign a default value to a variable, instead of keeping it undefined:

```
 my Str $bar is default("");
```

`$bar` will be `Str` only if it's assigned that value type; if its value is deleted via assigning `Nil` it will default again to the empty string. As a matter of fact, the default for a variable is its type object, so:

```
my Str $foo;
my $bar = Str;
say $foo eqv $bar
```

will, in fact, return True.

Comment: Right, so how can we determine whether we've got the default value or if it's been assigned the default value?  Or is that not possible?

Comment: @user0721090601 I don't really think it is.